PhpStorm CSS completion stopped working (Ctrl + Space gives me no suggestions) in Blade files
I am working on a Laravel project with vanilla Blade templates, jQuery & Bootstrap.
After the recent update, I am no longer getting CSS class auto-completions for Bootstrap in my Blade view:

I have tried the following:

Invalidate the cache
Reset the .idea folder (fresh import)
Marked the resource root folder correctly
Checked to see if power save mode is disabled
Tried installing the Laravel plugin

The CSS files are brought into my view/layout using the Laravel's asset() helper like this:
<link href="{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset('css/app-style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>

Is there a way to tell PhpStorm to do code suggestion from my project's resource root? It doesn't seem to introspect my CSS files when imported like this, strangely this worked before in the older version of the PhpStorm.

same here, even with classes defined in the file itself


Similar forum thread: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/18144222829714-2024-1-CSS-autocomplete-doesn-t-work-in-blade-php-files ; 2) Related ticket (related to that forum thread I believe) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-76922


Solution for the moment: rollback to 2023.3.6 until fixed or the reason & workaround is found.

welp this sucks, I don't remember all of the bootstrap classes top of my head :|

It is a bug in PhpStorm 2024.1. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-76922
It has been fixed already and will be available in the next minor update 2024.1.1 (later this month, on or around April 23 AFAIK).

If this feature is critical for you, consider downgrading to 2023.3.6 for the time being: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/other.html
UPDATE 2024-04-20:
2024.1.1 Preview build with the fix is now available. It can be installed via JetBrains Toolbox App.

great, im happy to wait few more days for it

For those who can't wait
Since yesterday, there is a new Release candidate for the version 2024.1.1
This version has the Bug-Fix implemented and it seems working well.
Install PHPStorm 2024.1.1
Install using the Toolbox App
Use the Jetbrains Toolbox and choose the 2024.1.1 in "Other versions".
Beware, Release-Candidates are not stable versions.

It looks like the RC versions can now only be installed via the Jetbrains Toolbox app.
The PHPStorm blog in the EAP section announced in the last RC version that a valid PHPStorm version is required.
