PhpStorm 2024.1: CSS support not working with Laravel/DDEV project on my Mac
I am using PhpStorm 2024.1 (new UI) on a Mac with Apple Silicon. I am working on a Laravel 11 project with DDEV/Docker. From my .blade.php files I cannot jump anymore to any CSS classes in the files of my project. It does not even work on old Laravel projects where it has been working before. I do not get autocomplete as well (neither to self-declared stuff, nor to for example bootstrap-CSS-contents.
The CSS files are located within a subfolder of the public folder.
I tried the whole repair process, re-indexing, checked for power saving mode etc. I haven't got any special settings for the editor as well.
Any further ideas? It really slows me down :-/
Thanks in advance!
PS: When I go into the generated cache PHP-files, it is possible to jump to the CSS declaration.
PPS: Looks like a known problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-76922

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78288302/phpstorm-css-completion-stopped-working-ctrl-space-gives-me-no-suggestions-i

Downgrading to 2023.3.6 helps. Known bug at Jetbrains. Fix comes with 2024.1.1 (at least they say so).
